# optimum: django clean or postgres function/trigger

Tags: django, postgresql, django-admin, postgresql-9.1

I have the following model.

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    email = models.EmailField(blank=True)
    address = models.TextField()
    city = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=True)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=STATE_CHOICES, blank=True)
    pincode = models.CharField(max_length=8, blank=True)
    district = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=True)
```

and I want first letter of `first_name, last_name, city and district` to be `capitalised` and the rest to be `lower case`.
Which process is more optimum, performing it in clean method of the model as

```
def clean():
    for field_name in ['first_name', 'last_name', 'city', 'district',]:
        val = getattr(self, field_name, False)
        if val:
            setattr(self, field_name, val.strip().title())
```

or as trigger in database using `initcap`.
I use postgres 9.1.

Comment: `Clean` is more appropriate . Suppose you need to change database or database server then you will need to execute trigger again .

Comment: I actually removed the clean function and moved to database triggers. Now the unique together throws integrity error. moving to database has the advantage if data is added from other sources, i.e. not from django app.
Any suggestions on how to tackle this.
and my question was about optimality not about appropriate.

Comment: You `should` write webservice if you want to allow same validation for all platforms .

Comment: Is this just an example, or are you actually enforcing capitalization of names and locations? This might not be a very good idea in itself, not all names start with an uppercase letter or contain only lowercase letters, and people usually are very particular about their identity, so automated messing with their names is not very advisable.

Comment: This is for business customers, which is only used for admin purposes.
The other option with us was to store it the way it is entered, and while display/print we format it. 
After some deliberation we chose the former.